# Is there a way to create an array of functions? - Blueprint UE4

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

I´ll explain my problem: 
As part of my game, when a player clicks in a specific button a group of 2 components of an actor will become invisible. The actor itself has a lot of components groups like that so I´ve made a function for each of the groups. 
The thing is, I would like to select randomly one of these functions and execute it. I could just make one big function with a lot of branches and use integers but I don´t want to lose all my work, there are almost 20 actors like the one I´m explaining + 30-50 components each.
So If there is a way to create an array of functions or something similar that would allow me to select a function based on a specific interger.

[One specific function for each group of components](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HUva2.png)

[An example of a function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7pa2U.png)

Comment: The simpler way to think about it is to try to make one function that randomly picks one group of components to operate on. However you can't have an array of arrays in blueprints but you can work around it with structs or component tags.

Comment: thanks, i´ll try that